# google.script.run errors , how do i fix this?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google script code

HI Guys, I have having difficulty  with basic code, and it seems to stop working as soon as i add google.scripts.run

your input would be greatly appreciated

The below code is my Google script code "Code.gs"

```
function AddRecord(name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  mainSheet.appendRow([name,new Date()]);
 

}
function startForm()
{
  var form = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AddForm');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(form,'Add Record');
  
}

function addMenu(){

  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom');
  menu.addItem('Add Record Form', 'startForm');
  menu.addToUi();
}

function onOpen(e){
  addMenu();
}
```

The below code is my HTML "AddForm.HTML"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function AddRow(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    google.script.run.AddRecord(name);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="google.script.run.AddRecord(name);" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems kind of buggy.

Looking at the `AddForm` file, you have created a function called `AddRow` that uses the [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) and that's a great way to proceed. But then you never actually used the function itself.

In the button you have:

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="google.script.run.AddRecord(name);" />
```

But the variable `name` is only defined in the `AddRow`.

Change the `onClick` to actually invoke `AddRow` and you should be good.

#### Modified code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function AddRow(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    google.script.run.AddRecord(name);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddRow();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, this is how I had it at first, unfortunately it also does not work, the form loads great.. but when clicking button add it never adds it to the sheet

Comment: bellow code should work fine. Try too add sucess and failur handler to see if the code make an error or if the function run well but don't insert the value in your sheet for other reason.

Comment: You should try to debug this a little bit on your side. Try to use `console.log` in the function `AddRow` and see if it is being called, can you access the name variable?
Also, for the server side function (Apps Script) it is associated with an spreadsheet? Try to get the sheet [by its Id]. Alternatively you can add a [`withFailureHandler`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withfailurehandlerfunction) and see what reason it is failing.